# tensorflow crossed column feature with vocabulary list for cross terms

Tags: tensorflow

How would a make a crossed_column with a vocabulary list for the crossed terms? That is suppose that I have two categorical columns

```
animal [dog, cat, puma, other]
food [pizza, salad, quinoa, other]
```

and now I want to make the crossed column, `animal x food` - but I've done some frequency counts of the training data (in spark before exporting `tfrecords` for training tensorflow models), and `puma x quinoa` only showed up once, and `cat x quinoa` never showed up. So I don't want to generate features for them, I don't think I have enough training examples to learn what their weights should be. What I'd like is for both of them to get absorbed in the "other x other" feature -- the thought that I'll learn some kind of average weight for a feature that covers all the infrequent terms.

It doesn't look like I can do that with `tf.feature_column.crossed_column` -- any idea how I would do this kind of thing in `tensorflow`?

Or, should I not worry about it? If I crosses all the features I'd get 20, but there are only 18 that I think are important - so maybe set the hash map size to 18 or, less, causing collisions? Then include the first order columns, `animal` and `food`, so the model can figure out what it is looking at? This is the approach I'm getting from reading the docs. I like it because it is simpler, but am concerned about model accuracy.

I think what I really want is some kind of sparse table lookup, rather than hashing the cross -- imagine I have

```
column A - integer Ids, 1 to 10,000
column B - integer Ids, 1 to 10,000
column C - integer Ids, 1 to 10,000
```

and there are only 1 million of the 1 trillion possible crosses between `A,B,C` that I want to make features for -- all the rest will go into the 1 million + 1 other x other x other feature, how would I do that in tensorflow?